# postgresql CONCAT function error when use in a trigger

Tags: postgresql

This might be a stupid question but pardon me, I'm trying to convert one of my MariaDB database into a PostgreSQL database. Here I'm getting an error while executing this function.
I cannot find what's wrong here,

```
create function tg_prodcut_insert()
returns trigger as '
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.id = CONCAT(1, LPAD(INSERT INTO product_seq VALUES (NULL) returning id, 6, 0));      
    END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Error is pointing to the `1` in `CONCAT` method, The type of id I'm trying to `SET` is `char(7)`

**EDIT**
I also tried this, this won't work either,

```
create function tg_orders_insert()
returns trigger as '
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO order_seq VALUES (NULL);
        SET NEW.id = CONCAT('1', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 6, 0));       
    END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still not working. I also tried `to_char(1, '9')` and it also not working.

Comment: Nope. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("`

Comment: Hmm. What's wrong in LPAD ? It wasn't worked with `LAST_INSERT_ID`, so I moved the insert query in to the LPAD and returned the id. Is that wrong ?

Comment: I added the function I tried first. All I want is to get the last_insert_id.

Comment: You are looking for `lastval()` or `currval()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: This works in mariadb though

Comment: Why a trigger anyway? Can't you just define the column as `identity` (or `serial`)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm converting my mariadb database into postgresql. I don't want to change the structure of the primary key. 1000001, 100002 .... Later I need to change this with some additional char values. like, ORD100001 likewise.First I'm trying without the `ORD` part.

Comment: But you do have a sequence that you created? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Oh really ? it's `4.18`

Comment: There is no Version 4.18, the current version is 12

Comment: Ah lol. I was just looked at pgAdmin. Yes it is 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to simulate some kind of sequence with that code by inserting into a table and then getting the auto_increment value from that.

This can be done much more efficiently using a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) in Postgres.

The error you get also isn't caused by the `concat()` function but because you are using the wrong syntax.

[Value assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) is done using `:=` in PL/pgSQL.

And there is also no `last_insert_id()` function in Postgres. To get the next value from a sequence use [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html), to get the most recently generated value, you can use `lastval()` but that's not necessary here.

```
create sequence product_id_seq;

create function tg_product_insert()
returns trigger as 
$$
BEGIN
  NEW.id := concat('ORD', to_char(nextval('product_id_seq'), 'FM00000000'));
  return new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

you will need to create a **before** trigger for that to work:

```
create trigger product_seq_trigger
  before insert on product
  for each row
  execute procedure tg_product_insert();
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25f86bce29ea23e6e53a9471cdaac111)

---

But it would be a lot more efficient to switch to a proper `identity` column instead and get rid of the trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but now it error is pointing to `:=`

Comment: There were a few typos in there, but that is none of them.

Comment: FYI, assignment can also be done with ```=``` per link above. What is the error message?

Comment: @Dilshan: I fixed some typos, the code definitely works (now): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25f86bce29ea23e6e53a9471cdaac111

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you so much. It's working :)